# Ubuntu 18.04 text is blurry when I turn up the refresh rate

Tags: nvidia, display, fonts, display-resolution

I'm using an Nvidia GTX 670 with the nvidia proprietary driver 690.

At 30hz All of the fonts look great, in fact everything looks great.  However when I turn the refresh rate up to 60hz many of the fonts become blurry and blotchy.  I tried using gnome-tweak-tool to adjust the anti-aliasing but no matter what I do the fonts are blurry.

Just a quick note, Im using a 43" Vizio 4K tv and I have the resolution set at 4096x2160.  Also, using the same tv as a monitor for my 2105 macbook retina with the same resolution/refresh rate everything looks fine, so I doubt it's the tv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTX 670 surely does not support HDMI 2.0, so it cannot do 4k 60Hz 8-bit RGB.

It is possible that the driver tries to do YUV compression to allow 4k 60Hz over HDMI 1.4, which cause the blurry.

Comment: thats a great point! I totally spaced it that for the mac I used a thunderbolt to active HDMI converter which was the only way to make it work.